# rake aborted! NameError: uninitialized constant even add :enviroment to task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake, google-sheets-api

I'm newbie to RoR and trying to create a task to import database from google spreadsheet by creating an Importer under lib/spreadsheet. but rake cannot find my importer even I added :environment to task according to some others issues in SOF. here are my files

lib/spreadsheet/importer.rb

```
class SpreadSheet::Importer
  def initialize
    @session = GoogleDrive.saved_session("#{Rails.root}/config/google_drive/config.json")
  end

  def exec(table_name)
    #do something
  end
end
```

lib/tasks/spreadsheet.rake

```
namespace :spreadsheet do
  task :get => :environment do
    importer = Spreadsheet::Importer.new
    importer.exec
  end
end
```

Error:

> rake aborted!
>
> NameError: uninitialized constant `SpreadSheet`
>
> /home/vagrant/workspace/ruby/kuwata-summer/lib/tasks/spreadsheet.rake:1:in `<top (required)>`
>
> /home/vagrant/workspace/ruby/kuwata-summer/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0
>   /gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:654:in `block in run_tasks_blocks`
>
> /home/vagrant/workspace/ruby/kuwata-summer/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:654:in `each`
>
> /home/vagrant/workspace/ruby/kuwata-summer/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:654:in `run_tasks_blocks`
>
> /home/vagrant/workspace/ruby/kuwata-summer/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:443:in `run_tasks_blocks`
>
> /home/vagrant/workspace/ruby/kuwata-summer/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:457:in `load_tasks`
>
> /home/vagrant/workspace/ruby/kuwata-summer/rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>`
>
> /home/vagrant/workspace/ruby/kuwata-summer/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>`
>
> /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load`
>
> /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>`
>
> (See full trace by running task with --trace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes..you can add it auto load, but an alternative is to add inside the rake file by "require"

Here is another way,

lib/spreadsheet/importer.rb

```
module Spreadsheet
    class Importer
      def initialize
        @session = GoogleDrive.saved_session("#{Rails.root}/config/google_drive/config.json")
      end

      def exec(table_name)
        #do something
      end
    end
end
```

lib/tasks/spreadsheet.rake

You need to incude the file by using 'reqire'

```
namespace :spreadsheet do
  task :get => :environment do
    require "#{Rails.root}/lib/spreadsheet/importer"  
    importer = Spreadsheet::Importer.new
    importer.exec
  end
end
```

Happy Coding!!!!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Capitalisation is important.

`Spreadsheet` is defined; `SpreadSheet` is not.

This is why your code is throwing an error when trying to define `SpreadSheet::Importer`.

...Or at least, that's what it *looks like* based on the limited information I have. If `Speadsheet` is not actually defined anywhere else in your code, then instead you can write:

```
module Spreadsheet # Can be a class, and can instead be SpreadSheet - as long as you're consistent!!
  class Import
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry for misstyping, but it worked now by adding auto load to config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)